# Higher current LED driver for persistence of vision display

Tags: led, power, current, driver

#### Project needs

We need an inexpensive LED driver IC that:

- Can source or sink at least 15mA/LED
- Has an SPI-like interface (not I<sup>2</sup>C)
- Has a separate latch pin
- Has at least 256 grayscale intensities
- Preferably at least 8 channels/chip

Can anyone recommend some devices to consider?  I think multiplexed/charlieplexed devices will not work for this project, but I am open to opposing viewpoints.

#### Why the project needs this

We are looking to drive 120 RGB leds (320 total channels) in a persistence of vision display. The nature of this device (bicycle-spoke mounted) means that to get the "horizontal" resolution (along the wheel circumference) of 10mm/virtual pixel we need to be able to load a full "column" of pixels (a radius) at 0.746 mS. The latch line is to ensure that the entire column will turn on at once, rather than one-by-one.  1Mhz I<sup>2</sup>C ends up being slower than SPI: using ATmega chips running at 20Mhz, the SPI subsystem can load 24 16-channel drivers in roughly the needed time (at 12-bits/channel). I<sup>2</sup>C at 1Mhz and 8/bits/channel (zero overhead) can program 320 channels in 2.56mS or more than 3x the time. Given the architecture of the system, we would really prefer to stay with a single core processor for ease of control and communication.

#### Previous work

**TLC5940** We've used [TLC5940](http://www.ti.com/product/tlc5940) (which can be had on Ebay in quantities for about $1/piece) successfully timing-wise. These drivers can officially sink up to 120mA/chip, meaning 7.5mA/channel (8mA if only 15 channels are used). We are considering overdriving the TLC5940s to reach 15mA/channel (225mA/chip peak), however, this seems unsafe. **Is it? Are there ways to overcurrent the LED driver in a more safe manner?** The TLC5940 can signal thermal error on one of its pins. The project is expected to be deployed in the environment of high air velocity: heat dissipation isn't expected to be a problem.

**75HC595** We have also tried using 74HC595 shift register for this. This has two problems. One is that 74HC595 can only source 8.75mA/channel if all channels are one. The second one is that using a PWM LEDdriver, we need to get 0.746 mS/update because each horizontal "pixel" lasts 0.75 mS. Manual PWMing means that for *N linear* greyscale levels we would have to update each shift register *N* times / 0.75 mS, which quickly becomes unwieldy once you realize that brightness is perceive exponentially.

Comment: How are you on liquid nitrogen supplies these days? ;-)

Comment: Link doesn't seem to work

Comment: Is this a [shopping question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq)?

Comment: FPGAs have lots of beefy IO drivers...

Comment: Given the level of programmability/correction on those parts, you could possibly just hang external PNP or NPN transistors for some current gain and then correct for the gain differences with the LUTS.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick. Maybe? I thought part selection was fair game. If I asked "what should I use to turn on a washing machine from an Arduino" there is a way of construing that as a shopping question too, right?

Comment: I'm guessing the real reason you want to use an LED driver (as opposed to a shift register) is that it can generate the PWM channels for you, leaving your controller more time to think about what LEDs to turn on, what colors, and when...

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier Added a note on the shift register. You are correct, sir.

Comment: @rawbrawb: Yes, if using TLC5940 the transistors would have to be PNPs.  Do you want to write that up as an answer?

Answer (score 6):

It appears that the reading of the datasheet whereby TLC5940 can sink only 120mA/chip is incorrect:

[image]

Rather, it seems that the correct reading of the "\$I_O\$ Output Current (dc)" value on page 2 of the datasheet is as maximum current **per channel**, which is also the interpretation arrived at by [Sparkfun discussion to this driver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10136).  The ambiguity of the phrasing *Output Current (dc)* is resolved in favor of *per channel* reading owing to:

- The fact that these drivers employ current mirrors, which given sufficient (voltage) headroom (see figure 5 of the datasheet), no more than that, do not use very much power.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frfN6K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To clarify the above point: In the schematic above, the voltage that the TLC5940 sees, i.e. LED Vcc (or \$Vcc_{LED}\$ but be above certain threshold, cal that threshold \$V_{HEADROOM/TLC5940}\$, which is around 1.25V for \$I_{output}\$ 120mA, and is .35V or so for \$I_{output}\$ 20mA. Any voltage at \$V_{OUT/TLC5940}\$ over \$V_{HEADROOM/TLC5940}\$ must be dissipated by the device as heat. For maximum possible current in the TLC5940, you would want to match \$Vcc_{LED}\$ to \$V_{forward}\$ of that LED, so that the TLC5940 IC dissipates the minimum power necessary, since power dissipation rating is a limiting factor on how much current the device can sink at each channel.

(and back to the list)

- The fact that in recommended operating conditions the maximum current refers explicitly to channels:

[image]

- According to the power dissipation calculation, assuming \$d_{PWM}\$ of 100%, VCC=5.0V, supply current of 60mA, \$V_{OUT}\$ of 1.0V (test conditions), dot correction of 1, we arrive at 5.0V*0.06A + 1.0V * 0.06A * 1 * 1 * 16channels we get 1.26W of device power dissipation. The PDIP package is rated for at least 2.5W at 25 deg C.

[image]